# Does not converge nor does it diverge to infinity or negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am stuck on part D of my problem. Suppose that $a_n$ converges to $0$ and $b_n$ converges to infinity. $c_n = (a_n) \times (b_n)$, Give an example where $(c_n)$ does not converge, nor does it diverge to infinity or negative infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Can you find $b_n$?

Comment: I believe I need to get $c_n$ such that it is something like (-1)^n

Comment: You need more though.

Answer (score 1):

$((-1)^n/n)\rightarrow 0$ and $(n)\rightarrow \infty$  what about the product?

Comment: Ah I was thinking too hard, missed the obvious. The product would be (-1)^n which simply flip flops and there is no limit. Very good

Comment: Absolutely right. Also you need to prove rigorously that the limit doesn't exist, i.e., $(-1)^n$ does not converge. Something like this works: Suppose that $(-1)^n\rightarrow L$. Then given $\varepsilon$, there is some $N_\varepsilon$ such that for all $n\ge N_\varepsilon$ we have $|(-1)^n-L|\le \varepsilon$. If $n$ is even, so $|1-L|\le \varepsilon$, if $n$ is odd $|1+L|\le \varepsilon$. Then $2 = |1+1|\le |1+L|+|1-L|\le 2\varepsilon$. Setting $\varepsilon<1$, we get a contradiction.